# Avoid null reference warnings when dynamically accessing properties of object using reflection in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to dynamically access properties of an object by using reflection:

```
class Program
{
    private class MyClass
    {
        public int prop1 { get; set; } = 1;
        public int prop2 { get; set; } = 2;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new MyClass();

        var propList = new List<string> { "prop1", "prop2"};

        foreach (string propString in propList) 
        {
            var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propString);
            // I get a compiler warning here: "Dereference of a possibly null reference."
            Console.WriteLine((int)prop.GetValue(obj));
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to prevent the "null reference" warning in an appropriate way.

I have tried adding a `if (prop == null) return;` check before the `Console.WriteLine`, but that doesn't clear up the issue. Instead it turns the warning to "Unboxing a possibly null value".

Is there a way to enforce that the strings in propList are names of properties in MyClass? In that case, I would be comfortable silencing the warning with a ! since I would know that the property would always exist. In my mind this would be ideal, because then I would get a compiler error when creating the list.

Comment: try `Console.WriteLine(prop?.GetValue(obj) ?? "");`  ... See if that removes the warning.

Comment: or just this ` Console.WriteLine(prop.GetValue(obj));` after the null test

Comment: @RobertHarvey That does clear the warning, but then I can't cast the value back to an int.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine((prop?.GetValue(obj) as int) ?? "")`

Comment: Saw your edit.  This is Reflection.  You were expecting compile-time checks?

Comment: @RobertHarvey that would be ideal, to just prevent the possible null from happening at the source.

Comment: Reflection is run-time by definition.  I doubt what you're asking for is reasonably doable.  Naturally, you can reflect over your types ahead of time to do the checks, but this is runtime behavior, not compile-time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the propList is hard-coded and so its values and their types are known at compile time. I was hoping there was a way to specify that those values had to be properties of the MyObject class, maybe similar to using an Enum to specify allowable options.

Comment: Not without a runtime check, AFAIK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it's not just the `prop` that may be null, but also the value returned by `prop.GetValue(obj)`.

Try

```
var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propString);
if (prop == null) return;
var o = prop.GetValue(obj);
if (o == null) return;
Console.WriteLine((int)o);
```

Or equivalent.

Comment: Ah yes, this is why the warning didn't go away.